# Large title crash application when view controller is opened for 2nd time in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a table bar root view controller set to navigation view controller with view controller that has only a table view in it.

When I set navigation bar large titles to always or automatic it will crash the app when I open tab 2nd time.

Error message is shown below:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _addScrollViewScrollObserver:]*    
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
 reason: 'ERROR: UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing _scrollViewWillEndDraggingWithVelocity:targetContentOffset:'
```

I don't have idea how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

[sotryboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiPCN.png)

Comment: It seems to a problem with specific controller structure in iOS 11. Hope Apple resolved asap.

Answer (score 7):

Found it!
Seems to be a bug with more than 1 Navigation controller in the stack.

So when my structure was (From top to bottom):

```
UINavigationController
UITabBarController 
UINavigationControllers (Different tab items)
```

If I removed to main NavigationController (Top), the exception is gone!
Hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: I would just suggest to set the preferedLargeTitles property to false on the root navigation controller.
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

Answer (score 2):

if you really have to use enclosing navigationController, you can set:

```
[navVC.navigationBar setPrefersLargeTitles:NO];
[navVC.navigationItem setLargeTitleDisplayMode:UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever];
```

on that enclosing navigationController before adding tabBarController inside:

```
[navVC setViewControllers:@[_tabBarController]];
```

so now you san use large titles on navigationControllers nested inside tabBarController. The point is that now UIScrollView has only one observer (navigationController) implementing _scrollViewWillEndDraggingWithVelocity.

Answer (score 2):

You should disable large titles for parent navigation controller (I guess you have more than one)

```
self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.  You have to set the first navigation controller to not use large titles.

The point is that now UIScrollView has only one observer (navigationController) implementing _scrollViewWillEndDraggingWithVelocity.

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = FALSE;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all of above answers don't really solve the issue and are overcomplicated. I recommend enabling/disabling large titles in each of your `UIViewController`'s subclasses, so they don't use large titles at the same time. Good place to do it is in the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```